# How to solve Error: read ECONNRESET in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am running an application using nodejs. when i am hitting in postman to `"http://127.0.0.1:27017/test"` this ip. then following error comes up
[image]

Comment: 1. don't post the snapshot of the code. SO has a feature to post your code in a neatly formatted and readable way.
2. Specify your error message and the data you're passing with postman.
3. The port you're using on postman and with express are different

Answer (score 2):

Port `27017` is where you mongoDB is listening, not your application. Your application is listening on port `8081`. As give by this line

```
var server = app.listen(8081 ...
```

So you need to change the endpoint that you are hitting from `http://127.0.0.1:27017/test` to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/test`